# How to exit from TTY mode

Tags: ubuntu, kde, tty, gui, kubuntu

I accidentally changed the video driver on my Kubuntu from NVIDIA to Xorg (if I'm not mistaken), rebooted my PC and now my GUI does not load after GRIB. Instead of GUI, I can see TTY mode.

I logged to this mode, tried press CTRL + ALT + F7 and CTRL + ALT + FN + F7, tried enter "init 5"/"init 6" and all don't help!

How can I load my GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do the command `startx` or install a display manager like `sddm`:

```
sudo apt install sddm
```

And then enable it and start it:

```
sudo systemctl enable sddm
sudo systemctl start sddm
```

Now, you should see a login screen. You can also select your desktop environment in the top left corner.

I hope it will help.